# Using Visual Composer with Angular 4

Tags: angular, visual-composer

I want to use visual composer with Angular 4. The problem is that I am able to create elements using visual composer but I am unable to make Angular interpret the classes of visual composer elements. Can anyone please tell how to make Angular 4 understand visual composer classes?? I have one css file containing some `vc` classes but that file is not complete.